# Printing TableView Contents in JavaFX

Tags: printing, javafx, tableview

I am learning JavaFX. I created my `TableView` and populated it with data. I added a Button such that when it is clicked, the table contents can be printed.

Here is the whole code for :

```
`public final class TableViewSample2 extends Application {
private TableView<Person> table;
private ObservableList<Person> list;

public void createTable() {

    table = new TableView<>();
    table.setEditable(true);
    list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));

//associating data with the table columns
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

    TableColumn SurnameCol = new TableColumn("Surname");
    SurnameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    SurnameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("surname"));
    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Emil");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(100);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(list);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, SurnameCol, emailCol);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    this.createTable();
    Label label = new Label("My Address Book");
    Button button = new Button("Print");
    //printing
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(" can I print?");
            PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
            if (printerJob.showPrintDialog(primaryStage) && printerJob.printPage(table))
            {
                printerJob.endJob();
                System.out.println("printed");
            }
        }
    });

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, button);
    root.getChildren().add(vbox);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Sample TableView");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

When I run the program, the table is shown as it is supposed to. Perfect. However, when I click the print Button nothing is happening. I was looking on how to print TableView contents when I saw this code. I tried to output some message in console but nothing is showing.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's about your 'can I print?'-output. Is this on your console?

Comment: @chris yes. because it was not doing anything when i clicked the print button, I wanted to see if it could execute those statements. However, it is not printing those statements even when I comment the code associated with printing.

Comment: The complete example prints ` can I print?` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code (and the class `Person` from the oracle site :) and it works perfect. As ItachiUchiha commented I also assume that .createPrinterJob() does not return an object. Maybe you haven't installed any printer.
NetBeans shows some details of my old HP printer:

[image]

Comment: I kept on trying and it worked at last. However, it is showing me these two lines of codes among others.  'Note: C:\Users\nationch\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TableViewPrint\src\tableviewprint\TableViewPrint.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.'  What do they mean?

Comment: I know that mesage but i never mind about. Just ask a new question here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using the primaryStage, its owner will be `null`

Try replacing `primaeyStage.getOwner()` with `primaryStage`

```
button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println(" can I print?");
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (printerJob.showPrintDialog(primaryStage) && printerJob.printPage(table)) {
            printerJob.endJob();
            System.out.println("printed");
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it is not showing. I even commented the code associated with printing but it is not printing those two console statements. Let me post the whole code.

Comment: Can you check if you are able to receive a value from `PrinterJob.createPrinterJob()` ? I guess this is returning `null` for you!