# Exporting tableview data to txt file

Tags: javafx

I'm adding data to Tableview like that.
I would like to export/write these tableview data to txt file for example. I wan't to create event for button.
How could i do that?

```
lisaTabelisse.setOnMouseClicked(l -> {
        if ((eesnimi.getText() == null || eesnimi.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
                (perenimi.getText() == null || perenimi.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
                (aadress.getText() == null || aadress.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
                (email.getText() == null || email.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
                (telefon.getText() == null || telefon.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ||
                (lisaks.getText() == null || lisaks.getText().trim().isEmpty())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kõik väljad on kohustuslikud");
        } else {
            tableView.getItems().addAll(new Sisendid(eesnimi.getText(), perenimi.getText(), aadress.getText(),
                    email.getText(), telefon.getText(), lisaks.getText()));
        }

    });
```

Comment: Loop through the tableview data and build a string that you can write to file.

Comment: Also, I recommend JavaFX alerts over JOptionPane.

Comment: You can print the `TableView`. Refer to [Printing TableView Contents in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998443/printing-tableview-contents-in-javafx) but rather than sending the `TableView` contents to the printer device, send it to a file. Refer to [How can you set Java PrinterJob to Print to a File instead of a Printer](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/how-can-you-set-java-printerjob-to-print-to-a-file-instead-of-a-printer/)

Comment: As @Sedrick says, just loop through the items and write each `Sisendid` object to a text file, in some appropriate format. There are various third party libraries, eg. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) if you want to robustly write in some specific format.

Comment: How does that loop in general should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply.
I managed to add data to txt file. Just a for loop worked well.
I noticed one other moment. 
Every time i insert new data, previous rows will be changed according to new data.
So everything will be same in the end.
How should i change that.

Comment: for a new problem ask a new question (and don't forget the [mcve] demonstrating what's going wrong :)